# categorical variables shown as numeric instead as factors

Tags: r, categorical-data

I'm trying to create a random data set in R that has metric, binomial and categorical variables. However, in the end when I check the class of my categorical variables R says they are numeric, but I need them to be factors for my further analysis. Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong here?
that's my code:

```
set.seed(3456)
R.dat <- function(n = 5000,metr=1,bin=1,cat=3) { 
  j <- metr
  X <- (matrix(0,n,j)) 
  for (i in 1:n) {
    X[i,] <- rnorm(j, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  }
  BIN <- matrix(0,n,bin)
  for (i in 1:bin) {
    BIN[,i] <- rbinom(n,1, 0.5)
  }
  CAT <- matrix(0,n,cat)
  for (i in 1:cat) {
    CAT[,i] <- factor(sample(1:4, n, TRUE))
  }
  X <- as.data.frame(cbind(X,BIN, CAT)) 
  return(X)
}

Dat <- R.dat(n=5000,metr=1,bin=1, cat=3) 
summary(Dat)
```

If I just sample like this:

```
x <- factor(sample(1:4, n, TRUE))
class(x)
```

it says x is a factor, so I don't get why it doesn't do the same when I use it in the function and loop...any help is much apprecciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop, If you switch to `data.table`, you can generate them by reference.

```
library(data.table)
n <- 10
bin <- 1
DT <- data.table(X=replicate(n, rnorm(bin, mean=0, sd = 1)),
                             BIN = rbinom(n,1, 0.5),
                             CAT = factor(sample(1:4, n, TRUE)))

## If you need you can add more columns
cols <- paste0("CAT", 1:3)
DT[, (cols):= lapply(rep(n, 3) ,rbinom, 1, .5) ]
cols <- paste0("BIN", 1:3)
DT[, (cols):= lapply(rep(n, 3) ,function(x){factor(sample(1:4, n, TRUE)) }) ]
DT
lapply(DT, class)

DT
             X BIN CAT CAT1 CAT2 CAT3 BIN1 BIN2 BIN3
 1:  1.2934720   1   2    0    0    0    1    1    2
 2: -0.1183180   1   2    0    0    1    3    3    1
 3:  0.3648810   1   2    1    1    1    3    2    3
 4: -0.2149963   1   2    1    1    0    2    3    2
 5:  0.3204577   1   1    0    1    1    2    2    4
 6: -0.5941640   0   4    1    0    0    2    3    1
 7: -1.8852835   1   4    1    0    0    2    1    1
 8: -0.8329852   0   2    0    0    1    1    1    2
 9: -0.1353628   0   4    0    1    1    1    4    1
10: -0.2943969   1   4    0    1    0    4    3    3
> lapply(DT, class)
$X
[1] "numeric"

$BIN
[1] "integer"

$CAT
[1] "factor"

$CAT1
[1] "integer"

$CAT2
[1] "integer"

$CAT3
[1] "integer"

$BIN1
[1] "factor"

$BIN2
[1] "factor"

$BIN3
[1] "factor"
```

Comment: that's awesome, I didn't know the data.table function yet, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
  CAT <- matrix(0,n,cat)
  for (i in 1:cat) {
    CAT[,i] <- factor(sample(1:4, n, TRUE))
  }
```

you create a numeric matrix `CAT`, and then you assign a new value to a subset of that matrix. When you do that assignment, the new value is *coerced* to the type of `CAT`, which is numeric.

Also, when you `cbind` the matrices `X`, `BIN` and `CAT` at the end, you coerce all of them to a common type. This would again mess up your variable types, even assuming everything was working correctly up to this point.

The rest of your code can also be simplified considerably. In particular, you don't need looping to reassign values to matrices; you can call the `matrix` constructor function directly on a vector of values.

Try this instead:

```
R.dat <- function(n=5000, metr=1, bin=1, cat=3)
{
    X <- matrix(rnorm(n * metr), nrow=n)
    B <- matrix(rbinom(n * bin, 1, 0.5), nrow=n)
    F <- matrix(as.character(sample(1:4, n * cat, TRUE)), nrow=n)
    data.frame(X=X, B=B, F=F)
}
```

Comment: okay, I think you just about saved my life, thanks a lot, this was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Because matrix does not accept factor vector, it will be coerced into numbers.
Just change it into a dataframe :

```
CAT <- matrix(0,n,cat)
CAT <- as.data.frame(CAT)
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: This won't turn `CAT` into factors either.